# Subsquare with most different numbers algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I was trying to invent an efficient algorithm for the problem below, but I think I failed.
I'm given a board **n** * **n** with different numbers in it and an integer **k** (k <= n) as well. I have to find a square **k** * **k** contained within the board, where the amount of different numbers is the biggest. For those examples:

n=4 k=3

10 9 8 1

7  6 5 7

5  3 0 2

3  4 1 3

n=4 k=2

1 2 1 2

2 1 2 1

1 2 1 2

2 1 3 4

the answers are following:

9 8 1

 
6 5 7 

3 0 2

1 2

3 4

My solution to this problem (in C++) is based on choosing the first square k*k in the left upper corner, creating a map linking the number (key) to its frequency of appearance (value). Then I move the square one column further by deleting the first column of the square in the map and adding the next column. When I reach the right side, I move down one row and left to the border. Then one step down and right to the border. And so on until I reach the end. The answer is based on the maximum size of the map at a particular moment.
I assume that this solution is quite poorly invented (but probably still better than brute force), I appreciate any suggestions. Can this problem be somehow simplified to a modified max rectangle problem? ( http://www.drdobbs.com/database/184410529 )

EDIT (additional details) according to Daniele's suggestions

In the beginning my algorithm analyzes the first k*k square, that is:
10 9 8 | 7 6 5 | 5 3 0.
As each element is analyzed, it writes the proper data to the map. So at first I have pair (10 -> 1) (number 10 appeared once), then I add (9 -> 1), (8 -> 1), (7 -> 1), (6 -> 1), (5 -> 1). Then I meet the next 5, so I change its occurrence to two (5 -> 2). And finally I add (3 -> 1), (0 -> 1). Actually my map contains 8 elements (because as mentioned above, 5 occurred twice). I remember this square coordinates and map's size. I move my k*k square one column to the right. Therefore I reduce appearance of elements from the first column in my map. So I delete pair (10 -> 1) and (7 -> 1) and change (5 -> 2) to (5 -> 1). And I add the last column: (1 -> 1), (7 -> 1) and (2 -> 1) (as all the numbers are new). Now I note that the map's size is bigger than before ( 9 > 8 ), so I save the current coordinates over the old ones. Actually I end my algorithm here ( my additional condition: if(map.size() == k*k) end; ) but otherwise I would "go" one row lower, than to the left until the border and that way I will have finished analyzing all the possible k*k squares.

Actually I'm looking for a better solution in means of time consumption as my solution is rejected by the testing system (I exceed the time limits). I consider it better than brute force as I don't analyze each square one by one but I may be wrong. Anyway, it's still not good enough.

I can attach the C++ code in case it will be easier for you, but I doubt it will help. I'm just looking for the algorithm suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for this challenging problem. I just make some comments about your post, as you are new. 1. please explain your algorithem in a more clear way (mabe with bullets?). 2. Which exactly is your answer? Maybe something like "Which is the best algorithm to solve the problem, where Best means XXXX (can be less operations, less memory..)"? Actually you already konw a solution (bruteforce) which works.  Anyway I'll think a little bit about it... it's very very intresting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I just expanded my post a bit by adding step by step description. I hope it is understandable now. However, I strongly suggest not to stick to my idea as probably I'm overcomplicating things.

Comment: I believe the number of sub squares you inspect over the square matrix can be expressed as `(n-k+1)^2`. So, it makes sense that your algorithm might not be very fast as n gets large, unless k gets large with it, because it behaves with quadratic complexity.

Comment: I guess you're right (or the complexity is even bigger). How can I do it better? Should I use some kind of cache?

Comment: on second thought, im not sure n^2 complexity is so bad, because the size of the matrix is n^2. I guess you could say your algo is linear complexity with respect to the number of elements in the matrix. when i read your problem description, my first thought on an algo turned out to be exactly the same as yours, so i have no better ideas.

Comment: Actually I can see some disadvantages of my solution, I'll try to improve the algo, but I don't know if it will make any significant difference. Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm sounds pretty good, with `O(n * n * k * log k)` time complexity and `O(k * k)` memory. If you know the values are small integers are in your example, you could get rid of the `log k` by replacing the map with an array. Otherwise, it's possible there is an inefficiency in your code that implements the algorithm. Try timing your code as you vary `n` and `k` to see if the time grows as expected.

As another possible direction, you can try a dynamic programming style solution. Define the function `f(x, y, a, b)` to compute the set of unique values (possibly a bitmap) in the `a` x `b` rectangle anchored at `(x, y)`. Then the problem is to find the maximum of `|f(x, y, k, k)|`. `f(x, y, a, b)` is computed as the union of 4 or more smaller rectangle sets with approximately `a/2` x `b/2` dimension. If the smaller rectangle sets are cached, you won't have to keep recomputing them. It will take a lot of memory for the cache but you can limit it by arranging your decompositions to use power of 2 sizes. For example,

```
  f(x, y, 21, 21) = f(x, y, 16, 16)
                    union f(x + 16, y, 4, 16)
                    union f(x + 20, y, 1, 16)
                    union f(x, y + 16, 16, 4)
                    union f(x, y + 20, 16, 1)
                    union f(x + 16, y + 16, 4, 4)
                    union f(x + 20, y + 16, 1, 4)
                    union f(x + 16, y + 20, 4, 1)
                    union f(x + 20, y + 20, 1, 1)
```

I think this approach is more like O(n * n * log k * log k) and so will only pay off for large values of `k`, such as greater than 1000.

Comment: I tried replacing the map with an array (or hash table) - it was significantly faster but still not fast enough.
Thanks for the hint, I'll try the second solution in near future! (Currently I'm working on something else :) )